# YouTube Video Playback Issues requesting for restart but still not working in Elementary OS

Tags: videos, web-browser, video-playback

Please help me on last question and this issue also, when i am playing video on youtube so getting below message on video and and its getting stuck on same point
**If playback doesn't begin shortly, try restarting your device**
I restarted but issue still is there.

As i asked last question about any video off line or on line, Audio and video combination issue i am facing and i have updated all pending update on same day but still i am facing issue.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes get this when the computer has trouble talking to a bluetooth audio device. It tries to wait for that before it continues playing the video.

If you are using a bluetooth audio device try reconnecting to it or re-enabling bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

For youtube videos you coud try using an extension called [h264ify](https://github.com/erkserkserks/h264ify), and it works on both Firefox and Chrome browsers.

What it does it makes youtube stream H.264 videos instead of VP8/VP9 videos; that being said, by default, youtube streams VP8/VP9 encoded video.

However, this can cause problems with less powerful machines because VP8/VP9 is not typically hardware accelerated.

In contrast, H.264 is commonly hardware accelerated by GPUs, which usually means smoother video playback and reduced CPU usage. h264ify makes YouTube stream H.264 videos instead of VP8/VP9 videos.

Github: https://github.com/erkserkserks/h264ify